# the best way to extract parameters of a xml in oracle through select

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a catalog in xml oracle but as extract value of a structure xml
for example;

```html
<Estaciones>
  <Estacion>
    <Nombre>Primavera</Nombre>
      <Inicia>Marzo</Inicia>
        <Termina>Septiembre</Termina>
   </Estacion>
</Estaciones>
```

and so on for all seasons

Then make a select to compare each inicioMes and as a result the station, 
whit this: TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT ()))  I extract a table in oracle xmltype, but as extract paremeters , i think use SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (), but is its structure.

Comment: so, you question is? what do you want to extract?

Comment: You haven't said what you want to extract, and in what form; or if you have multiple sets of values you want to extract as separate rows of relational data. Perhaps a more representative bit of XML and the output you expect would be helpful?

Comment: Please show how 'and so on for all the seasons' is represented in your XML structure, and what you want the result of the query to be. You're expecting us to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate that English isn't your first language, but it is really unclear what you mean and and are trying to achieve. I've added an answer based on what I *think* you probably mean, at least based on your `xmlsequence` reference. But more data and expected results would really help. Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have multiple sets of values to extract you can use [XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm) with a suitable [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb_xquery.htm). From the scant information provided this is a starting point:

```
select x.*
from <your_table> t
cross join xmltable ('/Estaciones/Estacion'
  passing t.<your_xmltype_column>
  columns nombre varchar2(9) path 'Nombre',
    inicia varchar2(10) path 'Inicia',
    termina varchar2(10) path 'Termina'
) x;
```

Quick demo with a made-up second season:

```
with t42 as (
  select xmltype('<Estaciones>
  <Estacion>
    <Nombre>Primavera</Nombre>
    <Inicia>Marzo</Inicia>
    <Termina>Septiembre</Termina>
  </Estacion>
  <Estacion>
    <Nombre>Otoño</Nombre>
    <Inicia>Octubre</Inicia >
    <Termina>Febrero</Termina>>
  </Estacion>
</Estaciones>') as xml_col
  from dual
)
select x.*
from t42 t
cross join xmltable ('/Estaciones/Estacion'
  passing t.xml_col
  columns nombre varchar2(9) path 'Nombre',
    inicia varchar2(10) path 'Inicia',
    termina varchar2(10) path 'Termina'
) x;

NOMBRE     INICIA     TERMINA   
---------- ---------- ----------
Primavera  Marzo      Septiembre 
Otoño      Octubre    Febrero
```

I have no idea what the second part of your question means I'm afraid, but this might get you on your way.